# Default \parindent value in report class

Tags: parindent

I am using the Report document class for my thesis. There is a section of the document where I set the paragraph indentation to zero using `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`. However, I want to return to the default value after this section. Is there a command to return `\parindent` to its default value? I never specifically set `\parindent` to begin with, I'm just using the default value. I'm hoping for something along the lines of `\setlength{\parindent}{something to indicate the default value}`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do that. One method is to record the default value. The other is to use groups. Second method is "the TeX way":

```
This paragraph has its usual indent.\par
\begingroup
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
Anything in here has no indent.\par
\endgroup
Back to normal.\par
```

That might potentially be a problem if your code is so complicated that you cannot keep track of the grouping. In that case, something like this can help:

```
% This part is in the preamble:
\newlength\defaultparindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\defaultparindent{\parindent}}

% Below material follows \begin{document}
This text is in usual indent.\par
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
No indent here.\par
\setlength\parindent{\defaultparindent}
Back to usual.\par
```

Note that grouping keeps certain things (such as `\setlength`) local, within the group. Some other things, such as counters, are inherently global.

EDIT: egreg's comment, below, was used to modify my above code.

Comment: I'd probably use `\newlength{\defaultparindent}\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\defaultparindent}{\parindent}}`. It's basically the same as yours, but avoids having general settings after `\begin{document}`. (The name is better, in my opinion.) +1 anyhow.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that is good. I will edit my original reply to do it that way.